# Which test to use to check the difference between samples of percentages?

Tags: r, statistical-significance, proportion

I have data measured from 14 samples between two conditions. I want to check difference between them. But the data is normalised and is in terms percentage (0-100). For example

```
var.A = c(9.302325581, 42.85714286, 47.3880597, 6.93131695, 6.968517863, 
9.535655058, 4.545454545, 10, 8.275862069, 17.5257732, 10.52631579, 
7.865168539, 11.76470588, 11.84210526)

var.B = c(33.96226415, 58.21256039, 33.83084577, 10.61452514, 12.54752852, 
9.371095377, 3.125, 20.21276596, 6.642066421, 11.62790698, 11.94029851, 
14.28571429, 8.333333333, 10.71428571)
```

For variable-A, I am observing median value of 9.76 and for B its 11.78. I want to check for whether this is significant or not. Which test would be suitable in this case since all observations are on scale of 0-100 ?  Do I use `prop.test` from R ?

Comment: Do you have the denominators?

Comment: Yes I have. Each value is derived by dividing observed/total.

Comment: Are the data paired?

Comment: Hi Glen, Yes. data are paired.I am interested to know whether overall change (mean or median) is significant or not.

Comment: That's critical information that should be in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with the proportions is that they'll have non-constant variance ... but you need the denominators to work those variances out.

The more usual approach would be to work with the original counts (the numerators), and keep the denominators.

```
pair      A        B
        X   n    X   n
 1      4  43   18  53
 2      .
 3      .
 4      .
 ... 
14
```

It's possible to construct a single chi-square test of the hypothesis of homogeneity within-pairs, by taking each pair's 2x2 chi-square and summing the statistics across pairs (giving a statistic that's approximately $\chi^2_{14}$ across all 14 pairs).

Alternatively, it would be possible to set this up as a GLM.

Comment: Hi Geln, Thanks for the answer. Here is what I have done for 1st pair. 


`Pair A.X A.n B.X B.n
1    4     43  18      53`

When I do `chisq.test` : 
`chisq.test(matrix(c(4, 43-4, 18, 53-18), ncol=2))`

I gee a `p-value = 0.008934` 

When I do `prop.test` : 
`prop.test(c(4,18),c(43,53))` 
I get the same `p-value = 0.008934` 

Any how, whn you say summing the statistics across pairs, do you mean I sum up the p-values from all 14 samples ?? Sorry for being naive.

Comment: No, don't sum the p-values, sum the chi-square statistics.

Comment: That can then be compared with a chi-squared k (`pchisq` can be used for that) ... unless you want it done as a bunch of 2x2 tests of course

Comment: Hi Glen, thanks again. I did sum up the chi-squared statistics and used it to get a p-value for degrees of freedom 14. This should be enuf right ?

Comment: Yes, if I understand your aim correctly, that should work fine. For the p-values, you'd use `pchisq(sum.of.chisq.values,14,lower.tail=FALSE)`

Answer (score 2):

The values are rescaled - they should retain their basic statistical properties, provided they have been rescaled the same.

I'm a little confused about what you have - 14 samples, and 2 variables, or 2 samples with 14 observations? Is it a paired situation, where you have 14 cases and have observed them twice (like a pre and post test)? Either way, the data are non-normal, so a t.test shouldn't work, particularly with a small sample size like this. Prop.test isn't what you are after - although the values are proportions, prop.test is for comparing two proportions, not two vectors of proportions. Try the Wilcoxon Signed-Rank Test, [wilcox.test](http://www.r-tutor.com/elementary-statistics/non-parametric-methods/wilcoxon-signed-rank-test). For the 2 samples, 14 observations case, I get:

```
> wilcox.test(var.A,var.B)

    Wilcoxon rank sum test

data:  var.A and var.B
W = 74, p-value = 0.2852
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
```

For the 14 cases, 2 observations each case (i.e. paired), I get:

```
> wilcox.test(var.A,var.B,paired=T)

    Wilcoxon signed rank test

data:  var.A and var.B
V = 39, p-value = 0.4263
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
```

Comment: Hi, Yes this data is from 14 paired samples before and after treatment (2 variables). I would like to check effect of treatment. As I mentioned in the question I am observing a median 9.6% and 11.8%. This increase of ~2% is significant or not, is the hypothesis I am trying test. I first thought of wilcoxon test but since data was normalized I hesitated to use.And in a recent paper where they do similar study, the mention they have used 'Proportion tests.' I am not sure what exact test they have used.

Comment: I'm sorry, I misunderstood what your original posting was presenting. Is there a reason you cannot pool all of the data together? You could treat each sample as a fixed or random effect, and if you know anything else about them, you could test whether they explain differences.

Comment: One other thing to consider: Chi2 and proportion tests are  sensitive to sample size, particularly a problem if you pool the results (however you do that). You should think about calculating effect sizes. For Chi2 that's simply square root of the standardized Chi2 stat (meaning calculate chi2 based on proportions in each cell, not counts).