# how do I compare percentages and show they are significantly different?

Tags: group-differences, percentage

Here is my data:
I have two groups (experimental group and control group)voting for 6 different actions, listed as A, B, C, D, E, F. The sample size of the 2 groups are different. Therefore, I am comparing their voting results in terms of percentage.

```
                A        B      C        D       E        F       Total
experimental   28.57%  53.57%   8.92%   3.57%   3.57%    1.8%      100%
control        19.7%   30.3%    30.3%   10.60%   9.1%      0%      100%
```

I want to know the difference between the experimental and control groups for each voting option. I am wondering if there's way to compare between those results and show that they are SIGNIFICANTLY different?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Assuming I have correctly understood what you're after, does the discussion [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/126392/which-test-to-use-to-check-the-difference-between-samples-of-percentages/126512#126512) cover what you want? That would test for any differences between each set of paired proportions (akin to a two-way ANOVA with interactions). If you're looking for an alternative of some consistent shift, I'd suggest a different approach (something nearer to omitting the interactions).

Comment: I think we need to know more about the original data to advise. Are the actions mutually exclusive? What are the rules about voting?

Comment: For the record, *some* of the statistical issues in evidence here are (1) the need to conduct six related tests involving correlated results; (2) the relationships between the percentages and underlying counts; (3) the differences in variance of the results arising from variations in the counts; and (4) differences in group sizes. It is unlikely that *pro forma* application of a textbook test (such as $Z$, $t$, or $\chi^2$) would be a good procedure. To help identify a good one, information about the underlying *counts* is essential.